# Three.js Reseting Matrix before Transformation

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, transformation, matrix-multiplication

I want to apply the same matrix transformation to a `three.js` mesh multiple times, but I only ever want the transformation as describe by the first transform. How can I "reset" the mesh's matrix to its pre transformation value before I re-apply the transformation?

I have tried the following, but it hasn't worked

```
const identity = model.matrix.identity();
model.matrix = identity;
model.matrixWorld = identity;
model.updateMatrix();
model.updateMatrixWorld();
model.applyMatrix4(newMatrix);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** *Replacing my entire answer because I was unaware that `Object3D.applyMatrix4` updates the `position`/`quaterion`/`scale` properties in addition to modifying the `matrix`.*

The easiest way to approach this is to back-up the model's original `matrix` property, and copy it back in place before the next update. This can be accomplished using [`Object3D.userData`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.userData).

```js
// before doing any updates, ensure the local matrix is set from postion/quaternion/scale:
model.updateMatrix();

// back-up the matrix:
model.userData.originalMatrix = model.matrix.clone();

// reset the model before each update
model.userData.originalMatrix.decompose( model.position, model.quaternion, model.scale );
model.matrix.copy( model.userData.originalMatrix );
```

Comment: I don't think this work. I've created this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-elgamal-fbzni and added your code. The model does not appear to be reset before the transformation is applied a second time. Thanks!

Comment: @withintheruins14 I was missing something in my understanding. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-reset-matrix/36939):

```
newMatrix.decompose(model.position, model.quaternion, model.scale);
model.updateMatrix();
```

or using applyMatrix4 method and some "first transformation":

```
var identityMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().identity(); //any "first transformation" matrix
identityMatrix.decompose(model.position, model.quaternion, model.scale);
model.updateMatrix();

model.applyMatrix4(newMatrix);
model.updateMatrix();
```